# System log auto generate

Tags: magento-1.9, system.log

```
2016-04-13T05:30:56+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 4: parser error : error parsing attribute name  in app\code\core\Mage\AdminNotification\Model\Feed.php on line 173
2016-04-13T05:30:56+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): ts}if(&quot;function&quot;==typeof __nr_require)return __nr_require;for(var o=0;o&lt;n.length  in app\code\core\Mage\AdminNotification\Model\Feed.php on line 173
2016-04-13T05:30:56+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct():                                                                                ^  in app\code\core\Mage\AdminNotification\Model\Feed.php on line 173
2016-04-13T05:30:56+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 4: parser error : attributes construct error  in app\code\core\Mage\AdminNotification\Model\Feed.php on line 173
2016-04-13T05:30:56+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): ts}if(&quot;function&quot;==typeof __nr_require)return __nr_require;for(var o=0;o&lt;n.length  in app\code\core\Mage\AdminNotification\Model\Feed.php on line 173
2016-04-13T05:30:56+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct():                                                                                ^  in app\code\core\Mage\AdminNotification\Model\Feed.php on line 173
2016-04-13T05:30:56+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 4: parser error : Couldn't find end of Start Tag n.length line 4  in app\code\core\Mage\AdminNotification\Model\Feed.php on line 173
2016-04-13T05:30:56+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): ts}if(&quot;function&quot;==typeof __nr_require)return __nr_require;for(var o=0;o&lt;n.length  in app\code\core\Mage\AdminNotification\Model\Feed.php on line 173
2016-04-13T05:30:56+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct():                                                                                ^  in app\code\core\Mage\AdminNotification\Model\Feed.php on line 173
```

I got this error in my site i don't know what is the problem any one guide me what is the problem ?

Answer (score 3):

If you take a look at the function `getFeedData()` in class `Mage_AdminNotification_Model_Feed` you can see that your error line `173` is Magento calling `new SimpleXMLElement` with a parameter `$data`.

```
/**
 * Retrieve feed data as XML element
 *
 * @return SimpleXMLElement
 */
public function getFeedData()
{
    $curl = new Varien_Http_Adapter_Curl();
    $curl->setConfig(array(
        'timeout'   => 2
    ));
    $curl->write(Zend_Http_Client::GET, $this->getFeedUrl(), '1.0');
    $data = $curl->read();
    if ($data === false) {
        return false;
    }
    $data = preg_split('/^\r?$/m', $data, 2);
    $data = trim($data[1]);
    $curl->close();

    try {
        $xml  = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        return false;
    }

    return $xml;
}
```

Here `$data` is the return of a `cURL` call on Magento feed, so the problem is probably that the return from Magento is not correctly formated.
If this error persist you may think about your file encoding but the first explanation seems to be the most probable to me.

---

Basically your error mean that `$data` value is `ts}if(&quot;function&quot;==typeof __nr_require)return __nr_require;for(var o=0;o&lt;n.length` so that is why I telling you it is most probably a Magento side error, not yours.

Comment: Sorry i am not getting what i need to be done

Comment: In my opinion that is a Magento side issue. You can add a `Mage::log($data, null, 'debug.log');` to see the return of Magento Feed. The log will be in `/var/log/debug.log`

Comment: Where i need to add this after this $curl->close(); or where

Comment: You can add this right after the `try` and just before the `$xml = ...."

Comment: ya i added but it's not created  'debug.log'

Comment: You have to wait for the next cron process. Admin notification are reached with crons (which I forget cron name).

Comment: Okay i will let you know

Comment: it shows all notification only

Comment: Basically your error mean that `$data` value is `ts}if(&quot;function&quot;==typeof __nr_require)return __nr_require;for(var o=0;o&lt;n.length` so that is why I telling you it is most probably a Magento side error, not yours.

Comment: Did you still have the error ?

Comment: Yes still i have that error How to fix that

Comment: You tell me that `Mage::log($data, null, 'debug.log');` between the `try {` and the `$xml  = ` that only show you the notifications ?   
If that is the case take a look at the class `SimpleXMLElement` maybe there is a typo in there.

Comment: Yes it shows only notification only

Comment: OK take a look at `SimpleXMLElement` class there is maybe a typo in it. Do you have other XML issue on your website ?

Comment: No XML Issue where i needs to check this SimpleXMLElement

Answer (score 1):

It looks like something is breaking the adminhtml feed module.

The cause could be a third-party module that is retrieving invalid XML.

Check whether your site code contains any class which extends **Mage_AdminNotification_Model_Feed**.

Once you find it:

->Try to disable that module from `app/etc/modules/`

->Clean the system.log.

->See if the error is gone.

Once you've determined which module is creating the issue, contacting the module's developer and notifying them about the issue.

Comment: I dismissed this possibility because when he put logs in the function which causes the error, the logs are generating and if you take a look at my answer this function have no dependency to others class functions.

Comment: it's probably coming from third party.If you disable extension you can find exact area of error.You have not given solution you have just clarify why the error is there

Comment: In this case I can not see how that the `Mage::log()` can works ? This is a standalone function I did not see how a third party extension can override it and still working when it debug in it ? Thank you.